# Error in [: incorrect number of dimensions (while executing Shiny R code)

Tags: r, shiny

I am getting errors as "Warning: Error in grepl: invalid 'pattern' argument" and "Error in [: incorrect number of dimensions" (in UI) while executing shiny code. please help. below is the snippet of the code. I am getting error when I am un-commenting last line

```
  library(MASS)
  library(shinythemes)
  library(shiny)
  library(ggplot2)

  mass.tmp <- data(package = "MASS")[3]
  mass.datasets <- as.vector(mass.tmp$results[,3])

  ui <- fluidPage(

    theme = shinytheme("superhero"),
    titlePanel("Linear Regression Modelling"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("dsname", "Dataset:",choices = c(mass.datasets)),
        uiOutput("y_axis"),
        uiOutput("x_axis")
      )     ,
      mainPanel(
        tags$br(),
        tags$br(),
        "R-squared:",
        tags$span(tags$b(textOutput("rsquared")),style="color:blue")
      )

    )
  )
  server <- function(input, output) {

    output$x_axis <- renderUI({
      col_opts <- get(input$dsname)
      selectInput("x_axis2", "Independent Variable:", choices = c(names(col_opts)))
    })

    cols2 <- reactive({
      col_opts2 <- get(input$dsname)
      #names(col_opts2)[!grepl(input$x_axis2, names(col_opts2))]
    })

    output$y_axis <- renderUI({
      selectInput("y_axis2", "Dependent Variable:", choices = c(names(cols2())))
    })

    model <- reactive({
       #lm(input$dsname[,names(input$dsname) %in% input$y_axis2] ~ input$dsname[,names(input$dsname) %in% input$x_axis2])
       #tmp <- paste(input$y_axis2,"~",input$x_axis2,sep = " ")

        lm( input$y_axis2 ~ input$x_axis2 , data = input$dsname ) 
    })

    model_summary <- reactive({summary(model())})
    output$rsquared <- renderText({  model_summary()$r.squared   }) 

  }

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: pls provide a fully reproducible example.

Comment: I have edited my post. Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

Yes thats better.
There a multiple errors:
We shouldnt debug it all for you, but here are quite some pointers.
That should help you to find them all.

1) 
You are using: `input$x_axis` and `input$y_axis` but defined it with a "2" at the end. So adapt that.

2) 
You should define:

`cols2 <- reactive({
      col_opts2 <- get(input$dsname)
      names(col_opts2)[!grepl(input$x_axis2, names(col_opts2))]
    })`

outside the `renderUI` function.

3) Moreover, there seems to be something wrong with this snippet:
`names(col_opts2)[!grepl(input$x_axis2, names(col_opts2))]`

Finally, I would check if you produce NULLS and prohibit that by `!is.null()`.

Edit: Question update:

You tried to build the `lm()`formula by strings, which you can test outside of shiny: Will not work.
You should use the `formula()` function and come up with somethin like:

```
lm(formula(paste(input$y_axis2, input$x_axis2, sep =" ~ ")), data = get(input$dsname))
```

Comment: I am now getting error "invalid 'envir' argument of type 'character'" while executing lm function.  ----     model <- reactive({
        lm( input$y_axis2 ~ input$x_axis2 , data = input$dsname ) 
    })

Comment: Code updated. After debugging, I think there is an error in lm function. I am trying different things, but did not work out.